# Custom fonts (Roboto) not working in xcode attribute inspector

Tags: ios, fonts, xamarin.ios, xcode7, xamarin-studio

I have added custom fonts (Roboto) in xamarin studio for ios ,integrated fonts path in plist but these fonts are not working and not inherited in xcode attribute inspector.can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

While adding Custom font carefully checked these boxes. Otherwise xcode will not load custom fonts on runtime. Hope this helps you.[image: Adding Font in xcode project]